# sorting list of objects in Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

In Python, I am parsing an `xml` file into dictionary, using this [module](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/). The core of my code is very simple:

```
configdict = ConvertXmlToDict('tasks.xml')

for task in configdict['osmo_tasks']['tasks_entries']['entry']:
    print task['id'], task['due_date'], task['summary']
```

the above code will parse the `xml` file into dictionary and then iterate through `tasks` and print them. Obviously, it will print them in the same order that they were read from, the `xml` file:

```
1 736366 summary
2 735444 another summary
5 735796 blah
```

**How can I print the lines sorted according to `task['due_date']` ?**

This is a sample `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<osmo_tasks version="000212">
  <category_entries/>
  <tasks_entries>

    <entry>
      <id>1</id>
      <status>1</status>
      <due_date>736366</due_date>
      <due_time>53100</due_time>
      <summary>summary</summary>
    </entry>

    <entry>
      <id>2</id>
      <status>1</status>
      <due_date>735444</due_date>
      <due_time>55800</due_time>
      <summary>another summary</summary>
    </entry>

    <entry>
      <id>5</id>
      <status>0</status>
      <due_date>735796</due_date>
      <due_time>55800</due_time>
      <summary>blah</summary>
    </entry>

  </tasks_entries>
</osmo_tasks>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `sorted` built-in function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

`sorted` can take any iterable and a key by which to sort. Here's an example similar to yours:

**sorted_test.py**

```
configdict = {
        'tasks': {
            'entries': [
                { 'id': 1, 'date': 736366 },
                { 'id': 2, 'date': 735444 },
                { 'id': 3, 'date': 735796 }
                ]
            }
        }

tasks = sorted([ t for t in configdict['tasks']['entries'] ], key=lambda task: task['date'])

print repr(tasks)
```

Result:

```
[{'date': 735444, 'id': 2}, {'date': 735796, 'id': 3}, {'date': 736366, 'id': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` with a custom key function `key` for sorting

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Something like:

```
sorted(configdict,key=lambda x: x['due_date'])
```

Comment: A custom `key` function is better than a custom `cmp` - in this case something like `operator.itemgetter('due_date')`.

Comment: Agree. Modified answer.